# Mysql fulltext search and integer field query slowing down performance extreme

Tags: mysql

My table consist of 600K records. The below queries have been troubling me for a while.

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `cvprofiles` (
  `tid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `partnerId` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'resume owner',
  `tenant` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'sellercompany',
  `lngId` int(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `firstName` varbinary(150) DEFAULT '',
  `lastName` varbinary(150) DEFAULT '',
  `profilePicture` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `mobileIsd` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `mobileNumber` varbinary(80) DEFAULT '',
  `emailId` varbinary(250) DEFAULT '',
  `altEmailId` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cvPath` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `cvFileName` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `genderCode` int(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `presentLocation` varchar(350) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `presentLocationId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `countryId` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'country to be maintained',
  `latitude` decimal(19,15) DEFAULT '0.000000000000000',
  `longitude` decimal(19,15) DEFAULT '0.000000000000000',
  `totalExp` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `anyKeywords` varchar(4000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `cvKeywords` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `presentEmployer` varchar(400) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `noticePeriod` int(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `presentSalaryCurrId` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `crDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `crUserId` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `luDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `luUserId` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `skillKeywords` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `industryKeywords` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `certiKeywords` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `prefLocKeywords` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `educationKeywords` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `roleKeywords` tinytext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `abilityKeywords` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `lngKeywords` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `infoKeywords` varchar(600) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'combination of fn,ln,mno,email,present employer designation',
  `jobTitleId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` bigint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `portalUid` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `salutationId` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tid`),
  KEY `partnerId` (`partnerId`),
  KEY `crDate` (`crDate`),
  KEY `idx_cvprofiles_firstName` (`firstName`),
  KEY `idx_cvprofiles_mobileIsd` (`mobileIsd`),
  KEY `idx_cvprofiles_mobileNumber` (`mobileNumber`),
  KEY `idx_cvprofiles_emailId` (`emailId`),
  KEY `idx_cvprofiles_dob` (`dob`),
  KEY `luDate` (`luDate`),
  KEY `idx_s_p_m_e` (`tenant`,`partnerId`,`mobileNumber`,`emailId`),
  KEY `idx_s_f_l_c_s` (`tenant`,`firstName`,`lastName`,`crDate`),
  KEY `sel` (`tenant`),
  KEY `c_c` (`crDate`,`crUserId`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fx_cat` (`skillKeywords`,`anyKeywords`,`cvKeywords`,`infoKeywords`,`abilityKeywords`,`lngKeywords`,`roleKeywords`,`industryKeywords`,`educationKeywords`,`prefLocKeywords`)
) ;
```

**Query1:** Below fulltext query takes "0.43 sec" for word "java" :

```
select  count(*)
    from  cvprofiles
    where  match(`skillKeywords`,`anyKeywords`,`cvKeywords`,`infoKeywords`,
                `abilityKeywords`,`lngKeywords`,`roleKeywords`,
                `industryKeywords`,`educationKeywords`,`prefLocKeywords`)
           against ('java' in boolean mode);
```

Result: 168944 records

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL       | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |     NULL | Select tables optimized away |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------+
```

**Query2:**

```
select count(*) from cvprofiles where  tenant=429;
```

Response time: 0.18 sec ,   Result : 845 records

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+-------------------------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | partitions | type | possible_keys                 | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+-------------------------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | icrd_resumeBank | NULL       | ref  | idx_s_p_m_e,idx_s_f_l_c_s,sel | sel  | 9       | const |  845 |   100.00 | Using index |
```

**Query3:** Combine fulltext with integer field takes more then 45 sec+.

```
select  count(*)
    from  cvprofiles
    where  match(`skillKeywords`,`anyKeywords`,`cvKeywords`,`infoKeywords`,
                `abilityKeywords`,`lngKeywords`,`roleKeywords`,
                `industryKeywords`,`educationKeywords`,`prefLocKeywords`)
           against ('java' in boolean mode)
      and  tenant=429;
```

Response time: 40.12 sec, Result : 452 records

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | partitions | type     | possible_keys                        | key    | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                             |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | icrd_resumeBank | NULL       | fulltext | idx_s_p_m_e,idx_s_f_l_c_s,sel,fx_cat | fx_cat | 0       | const |    1 |     5.00 | Using where; Ft_hints: no_ranking |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------------------+
```

None of the combinations of the query are working. How to improve performance of the query of  fulltext with integer fields?

- Using MySQL version: 5.7
- Storage Engine: InnoDB

Comment: see the EXPLAIN of all queries

Comment: Please provide the `EXPLAINs` via the mysql commandline -- to provide them in text (not image) _and_ to see how long the `EXPLAINs` took.  Note that two said "tables optimized away" -- This implies that all the work was _during_ the `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 1):

The Optimizer is caught between a rock and a hard place --

- whether to use the `FULLTEXT` index, then filter out those with the wrong `tenant`.  (This is probably faster, and the formulation below *may* trick it into using it.)
- Or to start by fetching on `tenant` first, then do the `FULLTEXT` tests.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE cvprofiles` so we can see if this is even viable.)

This kludge *may* make it run faster:

```
select  count(*)
    from  cvprofiles
    where  match(`skillKeywords`,`anyKeywords`,`cvKeywords`,`infoKeywords`,
                `abilityKeywords`,`lngKeywords`,`roleKeywords`,
                `industryKeywords`,`educationKeywords`,`prefLocKeywords`)
           against ('java' in boolean mode)
    HAVING  tenant=429;
```

The `CREATE TABLE` may point out flaws in the schema that led to slugishness.

On second thought, my kludge may not help *in this case*.  It will fetch 168944 rows, then reach into the table to check that many value of `tenant`; this will be 168944 random lookups.  The speed of that depends on disk type (SSD vs HDD) and size of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  So, which disk type and what is that setting, plus how much RAM on the server?

Where I am going with the previous paragraph...  If cache space is tight, it *will* be slow.

This looks like a case where "index merge intersect" would be useful, but the `EXPLAIN` says it did not try that.  So,...  Consider filing a bug report at bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: 256 GB SSD Storage,16 Core, 32GB RAM
innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 2 GB, 
query_cache_size  is 500 MB

Comment: @ArunGavimath - Such a large QC is counterproductive.  Don't go above 50M.  Increasing the buffer_pool to 20G may help.

Comment: I have increased RAM to 64GB, searching first time for a new keyword it takes 20+Sec,  once its cached, 2nd time 3rd time the same takes 1 sec. seems like MySQL fulltext with combined with other filters gets slower and slower.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without the EXPLAIN statement and table indexes, however most likely MySQL is making a huge temporary table to store the result of the first match and then tries the second filter.

I would recommend setting the 'tenant=429' part as a subquery instead.

```
select count(*) from
    ( SELECT `skillKeywords`,`anyKeywords`,`cvKeywords`,`infoKeywords`,`abilityKeywords`,`lngKeywords`,`roleKeywords`,`industryKeywords`,`educationKeywords`,`prefLocKeywords`
        from cvprofiles
        where   tenant=429
    ) AS x
    WHERE match(`skillKeywords`,`anyKeywords`,`cvKeywords`,`infoKeywords`,`abilityKeywords`,`lngKeywords`,`roleKeywords`,`industryKeywords`,`educationKeywords`,`prefLocKeywords`)
          against ('java' in boolean mode) ;
```

Note that you will most likely need to name the columns in the subquery and access that that way.